# Custom Audit Trail in Access to capture login details

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a login screen that I built in Access, I need the UserName (which is a column in table "Employee"), to be stored in "Audit" Table which I have built to store changes that take place in the DB.

When I login from the custom login screen it should have the username captured in (tempvars maybe) and it should remain available till the user closes the program, i.e. during the session (logged in as lets say "user_x") and I also want this UserName to be captured in Audit table.

I got a code from the internet to capture the changes that take place in the DB but it uses the Access login utility. I want to change it to capture login details from my custom login table once a user logs in.

```
Const cDQ As String = """"
Sub AuditTrail(frm As Form, recordid As Control)
  'Track changes to data.
  'recordid identifies the pk field's corresponding
  'control in frm, in order to id record.
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim varBefore As Variant
  Dim varAfter As Variant
  Dim strControlName As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  'Get changed values.
  For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
    'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
    If .ControlType = acTextBox Then
      If .Value  .OldValue Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "Audit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      End If
    End If
    End With
  Next
  Set ctl = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine _
   & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

Username to be captured in Audit Table once a user logs in using the login screen.

What should I use in place of

```
& cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
```

to capture my userName coming from a successful login action from the custom Login Screen that I built.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the userName the user enters in your login form, just replace the `Environ("username")` with the value of the textbox from your login form. Lets say the textbox in your login form is called `txtUserName` then just replace your code with this:

```
= & cDQ & Me!txtUserName.Value & cDQ & ", "
```

The `Me!` refers to your form where your code gets executed (your login form).

Comment: so intsead of Me, could I use something like Form!FormName!txtUserName.value ?  Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Its `Forms!FormName!txtUserName.Value`